# Passenger Unknown Reason-Phrase

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, passenger

When I try to access my site throught main domain (example.com) I get message like below. But it doesn't happen if I access the my site through a subdomain. I'm using Passenger with Nginx. Any ideas on how I can fix this? Thanks!

```
HTTP/1.1 16797828 Unknown Reason-Phrase
Status: 16797828 Unknown Reason-Phrase
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 4.0.20
Date: Mon, 21 Oct 2013 09:06:42 GMT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your app returned an invalid HTTP response code (namely '16797828'). You should fix your app not to do that.